# ASan: heap-use-after-free after vector.emplace(push)_back in a recursive function

Tags: c++, vector, address-sanitizer

```cpp
#include <vector>

struct Node;

std::vector<Node> heap;

struct Node {
    int x, c;

    explicit Node(int x): x(x), c(0) {}

    void update() {
        if(x > 0) {
            if(c == 0) {
                c = heap.size();
                heap.emplace_back(x / 2);
            }
            heap[c].update();
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    heap.emplace_back(100);
    heap.back().update();
}
```

Consider the above code. When compiled with `g++ -fsanitize=address` (`gcc version 10.2.0 (Ubuntu 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04)`) and then ran, I get `AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free`. After some googling it appears that this error happens when I try to access a pointer that has previously been freed. Examining ASan's output shows that the object was freed by vector.emplace_back. I believe that this is a result of the vector resizing itself, supported by the fact that `heap.reserve(1000)` makes the code run fine.

I then tried replacing emplace_back with push_back, producing similar results. However, replacing the recursion with a loop works fine.

```cpp
int main() {
    heap.emplace_back(100);
    int prevc = 0;
    while(true) {
        int x = heap[prevc].x, c = 0;
        if(x > 0) {
            if(c == 0) {
                c = heap.size();
                heap.emplace_back(x / 2);
            }
            prevc = c;
        }else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

After further examination, it appears that the exception is being thrown after the first call of `update()`. Furthermore, accessing `heap[0]` and `heap[1]` is fine, but accessing `heap[c]` fails.

Now I am quite confused. I can't find any undefined behavior, nor can I see any reason for vector internal resizing to cause me to not be able to access an element. Moreover, I'm not sure why this fails with recursion only. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add a destructor to `Node` that prints when it's called (maybe along with `c`).  You'll be surprised.

Comment: Ain't `vector` resizes a <expletive deleted>?

Comment: Handy reading: [Iterator invalidation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules)

Comment: @StephenNewell When printing `x` in the destructor, only 100 gets printed. I believe the exception is thrown after the first call of `update()`. I'll edit this along with more information into the question.

Comment: When you call `update` on a node in `heap` remember that `this` refers to a node in `heap` and when `heap.emplace_back(x / 2);` resizes `heap`, `this` is kinda <expletive deleted>ed. That means using `c` in `heap[c].update();` is going to be quite an adventure.

Comment: @user4581301 Ah, I believe that is the issue. Replacing `heap[c].update()` with a statement accessing `c` also throws an exception. Thanks for your help!

Comment: When you have a good solution, assuming you don't just use your non-recursive version, self answer. I'd have answered myself, but I'm pretty sure the right answer is non-recursive.

Comment: I was going to use this in my answer. I'll drop it here because this is what @StephenNewell was suggesting in his comment above: https://ideone.com/Lk6d02 . You can see evil stuff like *Destroying 0x55676c529e70* followed by *calling update for 0x55676c529e70. c = 0*, which is clearly invalid because the object is dead. Eventually you get one where `this` got re-used and `c` is insane.

Answer (score 2):

As user4581301 pointed out in the comments, the issue actually isn't accessing an element in the vector but rather accessing `c`, which fails because `this` had been deleted by `heap` resizing.

In my particular case I wanted to write a binary tree without pointers, so recursion is necessary. Ironically the reasoning behind this was to avoid pointer pitfalls, but that backfired miserably. For future reference, I've found four possible solutions:

1. `heap.reserve()` to a large enough value that `heap` will never resize itself.
2. Simulate a vector with an array and a pointer to the index of the last element (basically option 1, but possibly faster)
3. Add something like `Node self = *this;` and access all attributes through `self`. Note: doing `Node *self = this;` won't work, as `self` will get invalidated along with `this`.
4. Just use pointers; they exist for a reason.

Comment: A note on point 3. I'm not sure this is 100% legal. Remember the program is still in a method with an invalid `this`. A quick look at the Standard didn't find anything that explicitly states this is valid or not, but you've guaranteed that `this` won't be used and should be safe in practice.